# Search a Spreadsheet for String and return partial row data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hello stackoverflow community,

I want to create a script to search a google sheet by name, as this file will be deleted at the end of the script. A new file will be uploaded to google drive automatically every week. This will be the basis for the script that will be running weekly.

The code runs fine, but returns undefined in the 4 output cells.

Example Data from a row in the Spreadsheet "LocafoxInventoryData_Automatic":

1||5b8ff4fc3e578c005487dcd5|60.0000|38.6300|19.0000|||2.0000

I would like to retrieve the last number in the above string. (after the last " | " )

I hope someone can help me out. The strings being searched for are the ids of the products: In the above sample "5b8ff4fc3e578c005487dcd5". This id can only be found twice in the sheet. I want to always retrieve the first one. The differnce between the first and the second product IDs are the first number in the string. There are "1" and "2".

```
function getData() {
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('LocafoxInventoryData_Automatic');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var id = file.getId()
  }
    var sheetData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
    var sspre = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Vorlage");
    var searchString1 = sspre.getRange('I7').getValue();
    var searchString2 = sspre.getRange('I8').getValue();
    var searchString3 = sspre.getRange('I9').getValue();
    var searchString4 = sspre.getRange('I10').getValue();

    for(var i=0;i<sheetData;i++)
    {
    //Column 1 should be searched
    if(sheetData[i][0].search(searchString1)!=-1)
    {
    var rowData1 = sheetData[i];
    return rowData1;
    }
    else if(sheetData[i][0].search(searchString2)!=-1)
    {
    var rowData2 = sheetData[i];
    return rowData2;
    }
    else if(sheetData[i][0].search(searchString3)!=-1)
    {
    var rowData3 = sheetData[i];
    return rowData3;
    }
    else if(sheetData[i][0].search(searchString4)!=-1)
    {
    var rowData4 = sheetData[i];
    return rowData4;
    }
  }
sspre.getRange('D7').setValue(rowData1);
sspre.getRange('D8').setValue(rowData2);
sspre.getRange('D9').setValue(rowData3);
sspre.getRange('D10').setValue(rowData4);
file.setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Returning Partial Row Data with Regex

Okay this is working for me.  I have a file named 'LocafoxInventoryData_Automatic' which is a spreadsheet with one sheet. I look for files with that name and if more than one is found I throw error so that you can figure out which one you want.

I then open up the file as a SpreadSheet with openById. I get the product id from the Vorlage sheet column I7,8,9,10 and I wrap them with a regular expression that looks like this ^1\|\|cw8vtfxa5owglp03btv22g9d.*\|\|\|(.*)$ .  Although in the code the backslashes `\` have to be `\\` double backslashed which took me a while to figure out.

So that get's the numbers at the end and I put them into Vorlage column D7,8,9,10. And then I set the file isTrashed to true.  I don't know if you want to return the data so I left the object in there but commented them out.  I also removed all of the else ifs.

```
function getData() {
  var filename='LocafoxInventoryData_Automatic';
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
  var n=0;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var id = file.getId();
    n++;
  }
  if(n>1){throw(Utilities.formatString('Error: More than file named %s', filename));}//Will present an error if there is more than one file
  if(id){
    var sheetData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();//I assumed no headers in this file
    var sspre = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Vorlage");
    var re1 = new RegExp('^1\\|\\|' + sspre.getRange('I7').getValue() + '.*\\|\\|\\|(.*)$','i');
    var re2 = new RegExp('^1\\|\\|' + sspre.getRange('I8').getValue() + '.*\\|\\|\\|(.*)$','i');
    var re3 = new RegExp('^1\\|\\|' + sspre.getRange('I9').getValue() + '.*\\|\\|\\|(.*)$','i');
    var re4 = new RegExp('^1\\|\\|' + sspre.getRange('I10').getValue() + '.*\\|\\|\\|(.*$)','i');
    for(var i=0;i<sheetData.length;i++){
      var rD1=re1.exec(sheetData[i][0]); 
      if(rD1) {
        var rowData1 = rD1[1];
      }
      var rD2=re2.exec(sheetData[i][0]);
      if(rD2) {
        var rowData2 = rD2[1];
      }
      var rD3=re3.exec(sheetData[i][0]);
      if(rD3) {
        var rowData3 = rD3[1];
      }
      var rD4=re4.exec(sheetData[i][0]);
      if(rD4) {
        var rowData4 = rD4[1];
      }
    }
    //var rObj={rowData1:rowData1,rowData2:rowData2,rowData3:rowData3,rowData4:rowData4};
    sspre.getRange('D7').setValue(rowData1);
    sspre.getRange('D8').setValue(rowData2);
    sspre.getRange('D9').setValue(rowData3);
    sspre.getRange('D10').setValue(rowData4);
    file.setTrashed(true);
    //return rObj;
  } 
}
```

- [Regular Expression exec method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)
- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

By the way it's quite helpful with sort of a problem to have your own regex tester written in the same language you happen to be developing in.  I'm sorry it took me so long.  If you run into additional problems let me know.

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working either. 

1. You have defined var rObj twice, is that correct?
2. sspre.getRange('D7').setValue(rowData1);
    sspre.getRange('D8').setValue(rowData2);
    sspre.getRange('D9').setValue(rowData3);
    sspre.getRange('D10').setValue(rowData4);

Are these even needed then?

3. How do I input the found values in the cells after the return?